How to check there is one or multiply lines in a box?
As the question title described, I would like to check if there is one line in a box. If true, then execute \huge, or execute \Large.
The following is the MWE, I want to use a judgement to combine the repeat definition to the command \@makechapterhead.
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1
  {
    \huge
    \parbox { .8\linewidth } { #1 }
  }

\chapter { test test test test test test test test }

\def\@makechapterhead#1
  {
    \Large
    \parbox { .8\linewidth } { #1 }
  }

\chapter
  {
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test
  }

\makeatother

\end{document}


Have you decided what should happen if it's one line under \Large, but two lines under \huge?

Are you referring to the lines you input, or the lines produced in the output?

do not do \def\@makechapterhead#1   {     \Large     \parbox { .8\linewidth } { #1 }   } that is adding 4!! unwanted space tokens in every call.

@Werner The lines produced in the output.

@DavidCarlisle Actually, I will execute this in \ProvidesExplClass... that the spaces will be ignored. So, I kept the coding style of expl3 unchanged in this MWE roughly.

but the spaces either spoil the output or for the ones after #1  completely break the example as it makes a space-delimited argument, people can only answer based on the example you provide.

You first measure the number of lines produced with \huge and store the number of lines. Then you can choose.
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \check@lines{#1}%
  \parbox{0.8\columnwidth}{%
    \ifnum\checked@lines>1 \Large\else\huge\fi #1%
  }
}
\newcommand{\check@lines}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{%
    \parbox{0.8\columnwidth}{%
      \huge#1\par\xdef\checked@lines{\the\prevgraf}%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{test test test test test test test test}

\chapter{%
  test test test test test test test test
  test test test test test test test test%
}

\end{document}



\prevgraf is a TeX primitive that reports how many lines a just completed paragraph has:
Chapter 1.
THIS CHAPTER HAS 1 LINES

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Chapter 2.
THIS CHAPTER HAS 2 LINES

[2]
Chapter 3.
THIS CHAPTER HAS 4 LINES

is logged from
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1% a newline here would completely break latex unless you comment it out
  {% this adds unwanted space
    \huge
    \parbox { .8\linewidth } {% this adds ignored space that is safer not to add
      #1% this adds unwanted space
      \par\count@=\prevgraf
      \typeout{THIS CHAPTER HAS \the\count@\space LINES}%
    }% this adds unwanted space
  }

\chapter { test test test test test test test test }

\def\@makechapterhead#1% a newline here would completely break latex unless you comment it out
  {% this adds unwanted space
    \large
    \parbox { .8\linewidth } {% this adds ignored space that is safer not to add
      #1 this adds unwanted space
      \par\count@=\prevgraf
      \typeout{THIS CHAPTER HAS \the\count@\space LINES}%
    }% this adds unwanted space
  }

\chapter
  {%
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test%
  }


  
\chapter
  {%
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test%
  }

\makeatother

\end{document}


You can measure the content set as \huge and condition on whether or not it exceeds 0.8\linewidth. This approach is commonly-used by \caption to see if it needs the caption centred or justified within the text block.
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\huge #1}% Store \huge heading width
  % Check width of heading and set \chapterheadsize
  \ifdim\@tempdima>0.8\linewidth
    \let\chapterheadsize\Large
  \else
    \let\chapterheadsize\huge
  \fi
  \noindent
  \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{\chapterheadsize \strut\ignorespaces #1\strut}% Set heading
  \@afterheading% Typical after-heading settings
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test test test test test test test}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{%
  test test test test test test test test
  test test test test test test test test}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

